# POST http://localhost:3000/login/aa/aa 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, angular, http-status-code-404, backend

I have an angular app and a nodejs backend server. I want to get data from my backend but when I try to connect to it with Angular HTTPClient, it says: POST http://localhost:3000/login/aa/aa 404 (Not Found).However, when I put the link manually into the browser, it works perfectly fine. Here is some code:

### service.ts

```
addUser(user: IUser): Observable<IUser> {
        return this.httpClient.post<IUser>(`http://localhost:3000/login/${user.email}/${user.passwort}`, user, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        })
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

### index.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
[...]
app.get('/login/:email/:pw',function(req,res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var passwort = new Passwort(''+req.params.pw);
  passwort.comparePasswort();
  con.query("SELECT u.Email, u.Hash FROM User u WHERE u.Email LIKE "+ "'" + req.params.email+ "'", function(err, result ){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
    res.send("test")
  })

});
```

Thanks for every answer and for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route in your backend is set as a `get` request and not a `post` request.

You should either convert your request to a `get` in your service with `this.httpClient.get...` or convert to a `post` request in your backend with `app.post`.

The reason it works in your browser is that the browser performs a `GET` request when acessing something using the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

In backed you declared a get method and from frontend you are calling post. your code in service should be :-

```
addUser(user: IUser): Observable<IUser> {
        return this.httpClient.get<IUser>(`http://localhost:3000/login/${user.email}/${user.passwort}`, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        })
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before using `/:email` you need to subscribe this **particular** element

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const User = mongoose.model("User");

    const userParams = (req, res, next, email) => {
      User.findOne({email:email})
        .then((user)=> {
          if (!user) {
            return res.sendStatus(404);
          }
          req.user = user;
          return next();
        })
        .catch(next);
    };

    module.exports = userParams;
```

then use that in express router by typing

```
router.param("email", userParams);
```

this way your router will get to know what the params you are trying to send

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file, you are creating a handler for a GET request (which is the default request sent by your browser while accessing your webpage)

But in your service.ts file you are trying to send a post request to the server which is not handled, so the simple solution would be to replace the line

```
return this.httpClient.post<IUser> `http://localhost:3000/login/${user.email}/${user.passwort}`, user, {
```

with:

```
return this.httpClient.get<IUser> `http://localhost:3000/login/${user.email}/${user.passwort}`, user, {
```

For more info you can read this: https://angular.io/guide/http